# Folders and files synchronization

Tags: windows

I am working in a company two days a week, I have a folder on my laptop that contains all the files I am working on related to that company.

I would like to be able to synchronize the folder with the company folder related to the project I am working on. So every time I come to work. it can sync the content of what I have with the content of what is in the company folder.

And I also would like to know when they have changed the content of a file, and I have done it to. To erase neither their new version nor mine.

Has anybody ever had this sort of issue?

Comment: There are hundreds of file synchronization programs on the market.  Have you tried one of those?

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to know what kind of files you work on: `I also would like to know when they have changed the content of a file` sounds  a bit like you're looking for a [distributed version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control).

Comment: I have tried freefilesync. But it does not help me fix the second issue which is. I need to know the same file has been modified in both sides if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Words files, windows folders, pdf, drawings

Answer (score 0):

if you want to monitor the changes of files or folders, you can try [Real-time file Sync](http://www.backup-utility.com/features/real-time-file-sync.html). this feature will automatically sync the changed files or folders to your destination path once you add, delete or modify your files or folders.